# Python logical `and` returning wrong results comparing lists

Tags: python, boolean-logic

```
y1 = [True, True, False, False]
y2 = [False, True, True, False]
y3 = y1 and y2

print(y3)
>>> [False, True, True, False]
```

What is going on here? the third item in the operation is `False` and `True` and this results in `True`?

Comment: `and` does not `and` every member of an iterable against each other…

Answer (score 5):

`X and Y` evalutes to:

- `X` (if `X` is **falsey**)
- `Y` (if `X` is **truthy**)

Any nonempty list is truthy.

So if

```
y1 = [True, True, False, False]
```

and

```
y2 = [False, True, True, False]
```

then `y1 and y2` evaluates to `y2`, which is `[False, True, True, False]`.

If you want to `and` individual elements of your lists, you can do it with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
y3 = [x1 and x2 for x1,x2 in zip(y1,y2)]
```

Comment: y3=numpy.logical_and(y1,y2)

Answer (score 0):

```
x     | y     | x and y
------|-------|---------
True  | True  | y
True  | False | y
False | True  | x
False | False | x
```

Since a non-empty list is evaulated as `True` in a boolean expression in python, `x and y` returns `y`.

What you are looking for is:

```
y3 = [a and b for a,b in zip(y1,y2)]
```